# SVN 401 Authorization Required

Tags: svn, http-status-code-401

So, this was working yesterday, but not today.

I checked out the code from SVN last week, did some changes, and committed them back, everything was fine.

Today while running *svn log*, i am getting this error.

> svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://..'
>
> svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (401 Authorization
> Required) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://..'

I am on Mac, through Terminal. Anyone else faced it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am able to solve it. The problem was i checked out the code using my colleague's credentials, which were disabled by now. I checked out the code again using my credentials. -

> svn checkout REPO_URL --username=USER_NAME

and it worked. That is why the error message "401 Authorization required" was showing up.